# My brand new fridge has a dirty mark and silver tape near the compressor, should I send it back?

Tags: refrigerator

I have just unboxed a new larder fridge and noticed that there was a dirty black mark on the back, just above the compressor, which then has had a piece of silver tape put over it.

The fridge is otherwise fine and seems to be working, though I'm not quite sure if the (burn?) mark is a sign that it might fail sooner than other fridges due to a fault in the manufacturing process.

An image of the offending mark is on Flickr: http://flic.kr/p/9c87gf

Comment: This is off-topic for this site (if you were thinking of repairing it yourself, however...) OTOH, if it is a burn mark, I think it would fall under the _defects in workmanship_ part of a warranty, so you should be able to get the manufacturer to replace or repair it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, take it back. It is obvious that the mark was caused by a burn. The silver flashing tape was placed over it in an attempt to hide the damage.